# R: how to convert a binary interactions dataframe into a matrix?

Tags: r

I have a interaction datframe in R, like this:

```
> interaction
     x y   z
[1,] 4 1 112
[2,] 3 1 104
[3,] 2 4  19
[4,] 1 3 154
[5,] 3 5 332
[6,] 4 1 187
[7,] 5 5 489
[8,] 2 2 149
```

i want to covert it into a matrix, take x as rownames, take y as colnames, and take z as their interaction value, x,y can take same value.

anybody knows how to convert? maybe just one step in R. Please.
 thank you very much!
-------------------2017/3/31---------------------------------------
or there is another edition of my question:

```
interactions <-data.frame(x=c(40,30,20,10,30,40,50,80),y=c(50,10,40,30,50,10,50,90),z=c(112,104,19,154,332,187,489,149))

m <- matrix(0,10,10)

colnames(m)<-c(10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100)
rownames(m)<-c(10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100)
```

how to covert the interactions data into matrix "m".
thank you!

Comment: I am struggling to see the relationship between your "interaction" object and your "ma" object....

Comment: Your question is not clear. How does the matrix of 0s relate to the first matrix (it is not a data.frame according to the style of output)? The second is an 8X8 matrix while the first has max values of 5 for x and y.

Comment: what is your expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this the sort of thing...? It assumes you want to add duplicates - such as rows 1 and 6 (both `(4,1)`). (See much better solution in comment below!)

```
intn <- data.frame(x=c(4,3,2,1,3,4,5,2),y=c(1,1,4,3,5,1,5,2),z=c(112,104,19,154,332,187,489,149))

m <- matrix(0,nrow=max(intn$x),ncol=max(intn$y))

for(i in seq_len(nrow(intn))) {
       m[intn$x[i],intn$y[i]] <- m[intn$x[i],intn$y[i]] + intn$z[i]
       }


m
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    0    0  154    0    0
[2,]    0  149    0   19    0
[3,]  104    0    0    0  332
[4,]  299    0    0    0    0
[5,]    0    0    0    0  489
```

In response to follow-up question - if there are more possible values of x and y, you can still use `xtabs` but add in some dummy data with the valid x and y values.  The row and column names will be the combined dummy and actual values (as characters rather than numeric).  Something like this...

```
xvals <- c(-2,0,1,2,3,4,5,2.5,7) #possible x values
yvals <- c(-1,1,2,2.5,3,4,5,6,7) #possible y values
dum <- data.frame(x=xvals,y=yvals) #xvals and yvals need to be same length
dum$z <- 0

m2 <- xtabs(z~x+y,rbind(dum,intn))

m2

     y
x      -1   1   2 2.5   3   4   5   6   7
  -2    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
  0     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
  1     0   0   0   0 154   0   0   0   0
  2     0   0 149   0   0  19   0   0   0
  2.5   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
  3     0 104   0   0   0   0 332   0   0
  4     0 299   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
  5     0   0   0   0   0   0 489   0   0
  7     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

Comment: If that's what they want, then it's just a matter of `xtabs(z ~ x + y, mydf)`....

Comment: your answer is very helpful, Andrew's "xtabs" is useful for me. Thank you! but actually my matrix rownames and colnames is more than "x"," y", there is some values that "x" and "y" don't have. Just like the matrix's colnames and rownames are (-2, -1, 0, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3, 3.5, 4, 4.5, 5). so i have to creat the matrix firstly. And others are not changed. Do you know how to deal with it? thank you.

Comment: @J.Wan - I have amended to answer to show a way of doing this with `xtabs`